# zk and sclass issue

Tags: css, zk

how to create styles for zk components, for examle grid? 
i try something like this:

```
<style>
.mine{
}
.mine tr{
}
.mine tr td{
 width: 16%;
 padding: 2px 5px 2px 1px;
}

.mine tr td input[type='text']{
 width: 100%;
}
...
</style>
...
<grid sclass="mine">
...
```

and it works.. but it's usual css, which shouldn't be used with zk.. i'm searching for better solution, please, help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this resource will help you out :)

[ZK StyleGuide Grid](http://docs.zkoss.org/wiki/StyleGuide_Grid).

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the updated document](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Guide/XUL_Component_Specification/Grid).

You may also refer to [this guide](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Guide/ZK_Class_Concept) about how to use *zclass*, *sclass*, and *overwriting* to customize your styling.